# Starting function in proving Cauchy Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

I'd like to know how to obtain the function $h(x) = f(x) - f(a) - [f(b) - f(a))/(g(b)-g(a)](g(x)-g(a))$

The function is used to prove the generalized mean theorem, i.e. $(f(b) - f(a))/(g(b)-g(a)) = f'(c)/g'(c)$ for some c in $(a,b)$

Comment: Explain 'obtain'.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht, some references I read simply "pull the function out of a hat". However, there is no explanation how to get the function.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by 'get'? You can define the function without a worry (so long as $g(a) \neq g(b)$); do you want to know why one looks at that function to prove the theorem? Then the short answer would be that 'it works'.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht, but there are also some references that starts from a clear process, i.e. defining h(x) = f(x) + d(g(x),and set F(a) = F(b), then find the value of d. However, the function h(x) which is used to prove the Cauchy MVT is not the same the above function

Comment: Have a look at the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Proof) of Lagrange's MVT, which is a special case of Cauchy's MVT.